# Retirar link do FORMCRAFT do wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Desenvolvemos um sistema para associação de proteção veicular e uma landing page para ele ([Sistemavalor.com.br](http://sistemavalor.com.br/)). Usamos o Wordpress para desenvolver a landing page e para desenvolver os formulários de contato utilizamos o plugin FORMCRAFT. Acontece que no final do formulário o plugin adiciona o link **"POWERED BY FORMCRAFT"**. Alguém sabe como faço para editar este plugin ou então conhece um outro plugin semelhante que não adicione este link?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, acredito que a solução mais rápida seja essa:

Adicione essa classe CSS no seu estilo principal.

```
a.powered-by {
    display: none!important;
}

form.fc-form.fc-form-1.align-.spin-.save-form-.dont-submit-hidden-.remove-asterisk-.icons-hide-.label-placeholder.frame-visible.field-alignment-left {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

A primeira classe CSS é para definitivamente esconder o texto e o segunda é para ajustar a margem.